# Regular expression for the date time format : "Wednesday, August 08, 2012 9:38:31.113 AM"

Tags: java, regex

I currently have:

`(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday),?\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+[0-3]?[0-9],?\s+[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9],?\s+([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][0-9],?\s+(AM|PM)`

...as my regular expression, but when asserting using a little test harness I found it fails. Where is it screwed up? I am getting date time text from a web app and asserting that it matches above regex.

Comment: Can you show us what it fails for?

Comment: Why are you even using regex to parse it?

Comment: TestNG just says assertion failure, no meaningful error. When using the test harness it says no match found...

Comment: How do you recommend doing it then @nhahtdh ?

Comment: @tebel: Jarrod answered your question. I only remember there is a class in Java that does this cleanly, don't remember which.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Wrong tool for the Job

The fact that every other answer that is trying to *fix* your regular expression, is about a different part of your regular expression that you got wrong; this should tell you that it isn't the right tool for the job.

Regular expressions are hard to get right when they are short and compact, one of this length will be a nightmare to get right and then no one will be able to touch it in the future for fear of breaking it in some mysterious way.

#### Idiomatic Java

`SimpleDateFormat.parse()` is the idiomatic way to deal with date information in `String` format in Java.

#### Regular Expressions are for Matching

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems - Jamie Zawinski

And [that quote](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/alt.religion.emacs/DR057Srw5-c/Co-2L2BKn7UJ%5B1-25%5D) comes from the `alt.religion.emacs` mailing list!

#### Poor Solution to illustrate why `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` is the right thing to do.

Anyway, you can match what you want with a regular expression, but you should **not** do all that **validation** you are trying to do. You are conflating validation logic with matching logic, the two seem to overlap in some areas but in this case validation should be code, not regular expression tests.

[`(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday), (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (\d{2}), (\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{3}) (AM|PM)`](http://rubular.com/r/1LXKOkkqdY)

The above expression will **match** your requested string in the title. But it doesn't try and validate the ranges of numbers and if you did, what are you going to do about **leap years and February?**, a regular expression would get even worse to maintain.

In cases like this, you should use a regular expression to do a triage on the data to make sure it *matches* a pattern or format, then pass it on to a real parser or pass the groups to a method that actually does the range validation and other things.

Comment: Yes, SimpleDateFormat.parse() is way better, did'nt know about this,  regex are tedious at best.

Answer (score 0):

Regex may not be the best tool for parsing dates, however here is the only thing that stands out to me in your regex.

You time appears to require three digits for seconds, and doesn't include milliseconds:

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Try changing it to the following:

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}
```

Note that you can also change all of the `[0-9]` to `\d` if you want to save some characters.

Answer (score 0):

You've left out the Seconds and you're using a `:` for the milliseconds in the regex but a `.` in your question title example. So try:

```
(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday),?\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+[0-3]?[0-9],?\s+[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9],?\s+([01]??[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9],?\s+(AM|PM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with previous speakers that regexps aren't right for this job, but here's an autogenerated snippet that will match your exact date:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="Wednesday, August 08, 2012 9:38:31.113 AM";

    String re1="((?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|Tues|Thur|Thurs|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat))";    // Day Of Week 1
    String re2=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re3="((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))";   // Month 1
    String re4=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re5="((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1})))(?![\\d])";    // Day 1
    String re6=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re7="((?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])";  // Year 1
    String re8=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re9="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
    String re10=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re11="(\\d+)";   // Integer Number 2
    String re12=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re13="(\\d+)";   // Integer Number 3
    String re14=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re15="(\\d+)";   // Integer Number 4
    String re16=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re17="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";    // Word 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13+re14+re15+re16+re17,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String dayofweek1=m.group(1);
        String month1=m.group(2);
        String day1=m.group(3);
        String year1=m.group(4);
        String int1=m.group(5);
        String int2=m.group(6);
        String int3=m.group(7);
        String int4=m.group(8);
        String word1=m.group(9);
        System.out.print("("+dayofweek1.toString()+")"+"("+month1.toString()+")"+"("+day1.toString()+")"+"("+year1.toString()+")"+"("+int1.toString()+")"+"("+int2.toString()+")"+"("+int3.toString()+")"+"("+int4.toString()+")"+"("+word1.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
}
```

If one deliberately wants horrid regular expressions no matter what, there's a brilliant tool available out there on the net: http://txt2re.com/